# "system" reboots my device after I allow it to in SuperUser?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, superuser

Today, a random SuperUser request from "system", with UID 1000, appear. I figured that it was nothing, so I accepted it. A couple of seconds later, my phone rebooted, or at least that's what I think it did. I saw the T-Mobile screen flash by really quickly; the Samsung screen did not appear. So, what happened and should I be concerned?

Comment: Did you install anything new before that?

Comment: Hmm... I installed a game from the play store half an hour ago, and a non-market game 1.5 hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed any task killer application that has super user permission granted, this might be killing all the tasks(including system critical processes) which might result in a restart. 
An eg. for this would be ZDBox. 
Try checking if that's causing the problem.

Comment: But wouldn't the system reboot automatically and not ask for SU permission?

Comment: If you've already granted access to the app in the past, that  is retained. You can change permissions from the SU app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to format user data via boot menu.
The boot Menu open via press the volume - and power button simultaneously.